# Migrate TFS to TFS including changesets

Tags: tfs

I need to download entire project from TFS including changesets and need to add to another TFS server with all changeset details.
Is this possible in TFS?
Please help.

Comment: I don't think it is possible if you are using TFVC as a version control since it is a centralized version control.

Comment: I made some progress,now able to download TFS project  and all changeset using  git-tf

Comment: I am only half done. After completing I will be adding the answer.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Answered . It worked for me. I am not sure ,is this the best option or not ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I made this done using git-tf and Powershell

I installed git-tf using the following link

> https://chriskirby.net/blog/migrate-an-existing-project-from-tfs-to-github-with-changeset-history-intact

I cloned my existing TFS repo to Git,by using

> git-tf clone https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
>   $/MyBigProject/MyMainBranch --deep

Inside the GIt folder there is a subfolder named .git,inside we can find a file git-tf.
Inside the file rename changeset to TFS.

To checkin GIT to TFS, configure the TFS folder where you need to copy the GIT. Folder must be empty.
 change directorty to the GIT folder in powershell.

> git-tf configure http://xxxxxxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ 
>   $/xxxxx/xxxx --force
>
> git-tf checkin --deep --autosquash

**Note:**
Commit time will be the current time and for all changesets and author will be the person doing the operation.
To keep the author you can try

> git-tf checkin --deep --autosquash --keep-author